# disabling a textfield on click of a checkbox in a grid in EXTJS 4.0

Tags: extjs4

i have two check columns and a text area in a grid like

```
      {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        id: 'app',
        text: '<b>Approve</b>',
        width: 100,
        active : false,
        dataIndex: 'appr',
        menuDisabled : true,
        listeners: {
            "checkchange": function (comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
                this.up("myGrid").fireEvent("checkAppr", comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts);
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        id: 'dec',
        text: '<b>Decline</b>',
        active : false,
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'decl',
        menuDisabled : true,
        listeners: {

            "checkchange": function (comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
                this.up("myGrid").fireEvent("checkDecl", comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts);
            },
            "afterEdit":function(roweditor, rowIndex,checked){
                this.up("noiApprovalGrid").fireEvent("editDecl",roweditor, rowIndex,checked);
            }

        }
    }, {
        id : 'declresn',
        header: '<b>Decline Reasons</b>',
        dataIndex: 'declRsn',
        //disabled : true,
        width: 150,
        editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
            id : 'decltxt',
            dataIndex: 'declTxt',
            disabled : true,
            maxValue: 100000
        })
    }
```

on click of decline checkbox, i need to enable the textfield. otherwise it should be diabled.if my grid has three rows, how can i achieve this functionality. Please help...

Answer (score 0):

I would not use "id". I would use "itemId".

```
{
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        itemId: 'app',
        text: '<b>Approve</b>',
        width: 100,
        active : false,
        dataIndex: 'appr',
        menuDisabled : true,
        listeners: {
            "checkchange": function (comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
                this.up("myGrid").fireEvent("checkAppr", comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts);
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'checkcolumn',
        itemId: 'dec',
        text: '<b>Decline</b>',
        active : false,
        width: 100,
        dataIndex: 'decl',
        menuDisabled : true,
        listeners: {

            "checkchange": function (comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts) {
                this.up("myGrid").fireEvent("checkDecl", comp, rowIndex, checked, eOpts);
                this.up("myGrid").down("textfield[itemId=dcltxt]").enable(); //or disable();
            },
            "afterEdit":function(roweditor, rowIndex,checked){
                this.up("noiApprovalGrid").fireEvent("editDecl",roweditor, rowIndex,checked);
            }

        }
    }, {
        itemId : 'declresn',
        header: '<b>Decline Reasons</b>',
        dataIndex: 'declRsn',
        //disabled : true,
        width: 150,
        editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
            itemId : 'decltxt',
            dataIndex: 'declTxt',
            disabled : true,
            maxValue: 100000
        })
    }
```

---

Edit!!!

Because you need this in your controller, and I don't know nothing about your controller this is a generic example.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        {
            ref: 'grid',
            selector: 'grid'
        }
    ],

    checkDecl: function if (checked) { 

        this.getGrid().down("textfield[itemId=dcltxt]").enable()
    }
});
```

The important thing here is the reference to the grid you declare on your controller.
If you declare a reference

```
refs: [
    {
        ref: 'grid',
        selector: 'grid'
    }
],
```

To use it you just

```
this.getReference();
```

Comment: How to write this this.up("myGrid").down("textfield[itemId=dcltxt]").enable() function in the controller